# Ruby, using a spec helper file to call "require_relative"

Tags: ruby, require

I have a set of toy problems with this directory structure:

- lib

  - 001-problem.rb
  - 002-another_problem.rb
  - 003-more_problems.rb
  - etc....
- spec

  - 001-problem_spec.rb
  - 002-another_problem_spec.rb
  - 003-more_problems_spec.rb
  - etc....

The spec files & lib files are named to match each other.

Inside of a spec file, let's say, it's from 001-problem_spec.rb, I can do the usual: `require_relative '../lib/001-problem_spec.rb'`

But that gets kind of old as I am planning to create dozens of files. I want to make a template. So then I tried this, at the top of each file:

```
spec_file_basename = File.basename(__FILE__)
cut_here = spec_file_basename.index('_spec')
lib_file_basename = spec_file_basename[0...cut_here]
file = "../lib/#{lib_file_basename}.rb"
require_relative file
```

But that is rather long & repetitive. I'd like to put something like this codeblock into a spec_helper file so that each one of my spec files can reference it like so:
`require 'spec_helper'`. Obviously, just pasting in the previous codeblock into a spec_helper file won't work because `__FILE__` will return the name of my *helper* file (ie: spec_helper.rb), not my spec file (ie: 001-problem_spec.rb).

Is there a way to get the name of the file that is calling `require 'spec_helper'` and then use that file name inside of my spec_helper file so the spec_helper can require the correct lib file for the spec file?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by creating my own directory structure.
You can follow the same and this may help you.

1) `problem/spec/t_spec.rb`

```
require './spec_helper'
```

2) `problem/spec_helper.rb`

```
require './t_file_helper'
spec_file_basename = TFile.basename.split('/').last
puts "===spec_file_basename===#{spec_file_basename}====="
```

3) `problem/t_file_helper.rb`

```
class TFile 
  def self.basename
    eval('$0')
  end
end
```

After executing `ruby spec/t_spec.rb`

- output : `===spec_file_basename===t_spec.rb=====`

So now you can execute your code as same in your spec_helper.rb. Because now we have `spec_file_basename`.